# What's the difference between Jekyll and GitHub pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, static-site

I'm starting to host my personal blog on GitHub pages and Jekyll seems to be a
good choice. But do I have to install Jekyll on my computer? I think Jekyll just
provides a way of previewing my site locally. Is it possible to host my website by the use of GitHub pages only?

Comment: That's totally possible to not use Jekyll at all. GitHub Pages uses Jekyll to render your documents anyway, and you don't need to do anything special. However if you want to preview your site locally, installing Jekyll will help. You can skip that of you don't mind constantly committing to your github repo to preview the changes on Github Pages live.

Answer (score 5):

**Concerning your title question:**

GitHub pages is GitHub's static site hosting service for serving your personal pages or projects straight from your GitHub repository. Jekyll is a static site *generator* that can generate your site from templates (read below).

GitHub Pages self-definition:

> GitHub Pages are public webpages hosted and published through [GitHub's] site. [Reference](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-pages/)

Jekyll self-definition:

> Jekyll is a simple, blog-aware, static site generator. It takes a template directory containing raw text files in various formats, runs it through a converter (like Markdown) and our Liquid renderer, and spits out a complete, ready-to-publish static website suitable for serving with your favorite web server. Jekyll also happens to be the engine behind GitHub Pages, which means you can use Jekyll to host your project’s page, blog, or website from GitHub’s servers for free. [Reference](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/)

**Concerning your questions:**

> Do I have to install Jekyll on my computer?

You don't have to. However, without Jekyll installed, you can only preview your site through commits to your repository. If you would like to preview the site locally, you will need to [install](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) Jekyll. Here's a link for [setting up GitHub pages site locally with Jekyll (make sure to select the correct OS)](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/).

Details: Jekyll's engine is already incorporated into GitHub pages, so it will run `jekyll build` internally. Pushing a commit to your repository will trigger the Jekyll engine to (re)build your site. If you wish to serve and view locally, you will still need to run `jekyll build` `jekyll serve` etc.

> Is it possible to host my website by the use of GitHub pages only?

Yes. While GitHub pages offers [native support](https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0) for the precompiling of various intermediate languages (e.g., Sass & CoffeeScript), any other languages not covered will require precompiling on your part before it is able to be served properly on GitHub pages.

Comment: Wrong. You don't need Jekyll to use Github Pages. GitHub Pages are powered by Jelyll so GitHub will do all the parsing that Jekyll typically does, sans a few features and the ibility to install custom Jekyll plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I should state instead that if the user wants to preview their site locally, then it's needed.

Comment: You answer is confusing. You said yes when OP asked "but if you *have* to install Jekyll on my computer" and went on to explain that Jekyll is needed to pre compile the files yourself. You don't have to pre compile anything.

Comment: You're right. I'm jumping a bit to things like SCSS, which will require precompiling. That was what I was referring to. Jekyll offers a gem to do that. Without the Jekyll gem, then it is required. Thanks for your input, I can see where it can be confusing.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but since 2014 Github has been automatically compiling `.scss` files, alongside with coffeescripts and SASS: https://github.com/blog/1867-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0

Comment: I see. Well my concern still stands as it doesn't cover possibly all the files that need to be processed beforehand. I'll be more general in making amends to post right now.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for the tips. Let me know if you see anything else that can be improved on.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes it is possible. GitHub Pages support the latest version of Jekyll.
>   You may refer to this
>   https://blog.github.com/2014-07-30-github-pages-now-runs-jekyll-2-2-0/

- [Native Sass & CoffeeScript](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) support - Simply commit a `.coffee`, `.sass` or `.scss` file to your site’s repository, and GitHub Pages will transparently output JavaScript or CSS when your site is published.
- [Kramdown](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/1988) as the default Markdown engine - In addition to better error handling, Kramdown supports MathJax, fenced code blocks, nested lists, tables, and much more.
- [Collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) - With collections, Jekyll is no longer limited to just posts and pages—it can now publish all kinds of different documents, such as code methods, team members, or your favorite open source projects.
- [JSON data](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) - `.json` files in the _data directory now get read in and are exposed to Liquid templates as the `site.data` namespace (along with `.yml` files).